# how do I remove load more button once ends fetching?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to implement properly a load more button, but once reach the last item from the current page then remove the button, but how can I properly do this?

```
<div className="job-overview-card">
{feed.slice(0, visible).map(feeds =>
)
}
</div>

<div className="job-card-buttons">
{currentPage > 1 && (
  <button
    onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}
    className="search-buttons card-buttons-msg"
  >
    Back
  </button>
)}
<button
  onClick={showMoreItems}
  className="search-buttons card-buttons"
>
  Load More
</button>
<button
  onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}
  className="search-buttons card-buttons"
>
  Next
</button>
</div>

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(3)

const showMoreItems = () => {
  setVisible(prevValue => prevValue + 3);
}
```

Comment: should it be the last `feed` or `item`? I don't see `items` state used on your logic

Answer (score 1):

After fetching your data from the Backend, either you organize with the Backend Developer to manage the pagination, or you just do it in the Frontend.

It is better to be handled by the Backend using `{skip: number, take: number}` for example.

However, if you need to handle this in the Frontend, Then you add a property to your class to store:

1. how many results are displayed.
2. total number of results.
3. available pages (divide total number of results / how many results to be displayed) then store this as array of numbers from 1 to the division result
4. active page which will be your pointer

so when the active page equals the last item of the array in step 3, you can hide the load more button.

Comment: i have the logic in the backend ,but once it reach the last feed element (100) per page in the front end, then I want to remove load more button

Comment: That's easy now ! you have the pagination handled by the `backend `so you only need the `total` number of results to be sent with the `results api request`. Now you have to know how much results you are showing in the page as a `frontend` and you have the total number of the results. By dividing the `total / number_of_results_per_page` you will get how many pages you have to show. Now if the `active_page_number = number_of_pages` then you can hide the `load_more` button.